# QGIS 3.4.11: Labels disapear from map when exporting as picture from the print composer

Tags: qgis, labeling, print-composer, printing

My question is basicly how to solve the issue mentioned in the topic. I have a map, where labels (city names) are visible both in the project and in the print composer. But when I export the map as a picture, the labels disapear. Is this a bug or do I need to choose some option?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: could you give us some clues? - may be a screen shot of the issue?

Comment: Did you try exporting with different resolution? Changing resolution from let's sys 72 dpi to 300 dpi.